# Monte Carlo in Python

Tags: python, finance, montecarlo

**Edited to include VBA code for comparison**

**Also, we know the analytical value, which is 8.021, towards which the Monte-Carlo should converge, which makes the comparison easier.**

**Excel VBA gives 8.067 based on averaging 5 Monte-Carlo simulations (7.989, 8.187, 8.045, 8.034, 8.075)**

**Python gives 7.973 based on 5 MCs (7.913, 7.915, 8.203, 7.739, 8.095) and a larger Variance!**

**The VBA code is not even "that good", using a rather bad way to produce samples from Standard Normal!**

I am running a super simple code in Python to price European Call Option via Monte Carlo, and I am surprised at how "bad" the convergence is with 10,000 "simulated paths". Usually, when running a Monte-Carlo for this simple problem in C++ or even VBA, I get better convergence.

I show the code below (the code is taken from Textbook "Python for Finance" and I run in in Visual Studio Code under Python 3.7.7, 64-bit version): I get the following results, as an example: Run 1 = 7.913, Run 2 = 7.915, Run 3 = 8.203, Run 4 = 7.739, Run 5 = 8.095,

Results such as the above, that differ by so much, would be unacceptable. How can the convergence be improved??? (Obviously by running more paths, but as I said: for 10,000 paths, the result should already have converged much better):

```
#MonteCarlo valuation of European Call Option

import math
import numpy as np

#Parameter Values
S_0 = 100.  # initial value
K = 105.    # strike
T = 1.0     # time to maturity
r = 0.05    # short rate (constant)
sigma = 0.2 # vol

nr_simulations = 10000

#Valuation Algo:

# Notice the vectorization below, instead of a loop
z = np.random.standard_normal(nr_simulations)

# Notice that the S_T below is a VECTOR!
S_T = S_0 * np.exp((r-0.5*sigma**2)+math.sqrt(T)*sigma*z)

#Call option pay-off at maturity (Vector!)
C_T = np.maximum((S_T-K),0) 

# C_0 is a scalar
C_0 = math.exp(-r*T)*np.average(C_T) 

print('Value of the European Call is: ', C_0)
```

I also include VBA code, which produces slightly better results (in my opinion): with the VBA code below, I get 7.989, 8.187, 8.045, 8.034, 8.075.

```
Option Explicit

Sub monteCarlo()

    ' variable declaration
    ' stock initial & final values, option pay-off at maturity
    Dim stockInitial, stockFinal, optionFinal As Double

    ' r = rate, sigma = volatility, strike = strike price
    Dim r, sigma, strike As Double

    'maturity of the option
    Dim maturity As Double

    ' instatiate variables
    stockInitial = 100#

    r = 0.05
    maturity = 1#
    sigma = 0.2
    strike = 105#

    ' normal is Standard Normal
    Dim normal As Double

    ' randomNr is randomly generated nr via "rnd()" function, between 0 & 1
    Dim randomNr As Double

    ' variable for storing the final result value
    Dim result As Double

    Dim i, j As Long, monteCarlo As Long
    monteCarlo = 10000

    For j = 1 To 5
        result = 0#
        For i = 1 To monteCarlo

            ' get random nr between 0 and 1
            randomNr = Rnd()
            'max(Rnd(), 0.000000001)

            ' standard Normal
            normal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(randomNr)

            stockFinal = stockInitial * Exp((r - (0.5 * (sigma ^ 2))) + (sigma * Sqr(maturity) * normal))

            optionFinal = max((stockFinal - strike), 0)

            result = result + optionFinal

        Next i

        result = result / monteCarlo
        result = result * Exp(-r * maturity)
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 1) = result

    Next j


    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

Function max(ByVal number1 As Double, ByVal number2 As Double)

    If number1 > number2 Then
        max = number1
    Else
        max = number2
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Interesting! I get about the same values as you. Could you post your results from C++ or VBA for comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with Python or numpy internals, the convergence is definitely should be the same no matter what tool you're using. I ran a few simulations with different sample sizes and different sigma values. No surprise, it turns out the speed of convergence is heavily controlled by the sigma value, see the plot below. Note that x axis is on log-scale! After the bigger oscillations fade away there are more smaller waves before it stabilizes. The easiest to see at sigma=0.5.
[image: See this picture]

I'm definitely not an expert, but I think the most obvious solution is to increase sample size, as you mentioned. It would be nice to see results and code from C++ or VBA, because I don't know how familiar you are with numpy and python functions. Maybe something is not doing what you think it's doing.

Code to generate the plot (let's not talk about efficiency, it's horrible):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

S_0 = 100.  # initial value
K = 105.    # strike
T = 1.0     # time to maturity
r = 0.05    # short rate (constant)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
plt.xscale('log')

samplesize = np.geomspace(1000, 20000000, 64)
sigmas = np.arange(0, 0.7, 0.1)
for s in sigmas:
    arr = []

    for n in samplesize:

        n = n.astype(int)

        z = np.random.standard_normal(n)

        S_T = S_0 * np.exp((r-0.5*s**2)+np.sqrt(T)*s*z)


        C_T = np.maximum((S_T-K),0) 


        C_0 = np.exp(-r*T)*np.average(C_T) 


        arr.append(C_0)

    ax.scatter(samplesize, arr, label=f'sigma={s:.2f}')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlabel('Sample size')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.grid()
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

*Addition*:

This time you got closer results to the real value using VBA. But sometimes you don't. The effect of randomness is too big here. The truth is averaging out only 5 results from a low sample number simulation is not meaningful.  For example averaging out 50 different simulations in Python (with only n=10000, even though you shouldn't do that if you're willing to get the right answer) yields to 8.025167 (± 0.039717 with 95% confidence level), which is very close to the real solution.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, appreciate your answer. I would just comment that in a financial institution, you might often be asked to come up quickly with some computation to quote a price or some related risk, and there's no time really to run 50 different simulations. I was just surprised that NuMpy, which is meant to be optimized for these sort of calcs, underperforms VBA for this simple example.